# Javascript - returning to initial state

Tags: javascript

I have an application that goes through a flow: basically it listens to audio from microphone, sends it to the server. The server then processes it and sends back an audio response. Throughout the flow this back and forth audio communication between client and server is repeated with some variations and using different modules at each stage.

To start and stop the flow the user just clicks a button "Start/Stop", such that when "Stop" is clicked the flow returns to the initial state, and if the user clicks "Start" again, he has to start from the beginning.

My current problem is that when the user clicks "Stop", the flow can be in several different states, and in each state the components I need to stop are variable, and some might not be even running while I try to stop them.

Is there a way to simply make everything return to "base state" in Javascript, as in just be the same as when the page loaded?

Otherwise I guess I needed to record the current state at each possible stage of the flow, and use `try/catch` just in case I try to stop something that isn't actually running. That feels like a really naive approach.

Comment: Not sure what is really the problem, can you post some code or a diagram, for multiple things that run on parallel and depend on something else you can use the observer pattern, where all your process subscribe to the event `start` and `stop` and then, you can notify them when button clicked, for the issue of `not runing` you can give each "stream" or "flow" a unique id, so that stop and start does not get mixed up

Comment: It depends on how other states differ from the "base" state.